# Comparing strings in this instances work differently, any reason?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++17

Can someone help me with this, please? The block of code in the green box works fine, but the one in red works but not really. It's checking if the emails have both "@gmail.com" and "@yahoo.com". I want it to check both emails so that if they both contain only one "@gmail.com" or "@yahoo.com", it will exit the loop. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string emailOne_, emailTwo_;
    bool valid = true;

do
{
    cout << "Email: ";
    cin >> emailOne_;
    cout << "Re-enter email: ";
    cin >> emailTwo_;

    if (emailOne_.compare(emailTwo_) != 0)
    {
        valid = false;
        cerr << "\t[*] ERROR: EMAILS DO NOT MATCH\n\n";
    }
    else
    {
        valid = true;
    }

    string myArray[] = { "@gmail.com", "@yahoo.com" };
    int arrSize = sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
    {
        auto found = emailOne_.find(myArray[i]);
        if (found == string::npos)
        {
            valid = false;
            cerr << "\t[*] ERROR: EMAILS MUST HAVE @gmail.com or @yahoo.com\n\n";
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            valid = true;
        }
    }
} while (valid == false);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code.

Comment: We can't even see the types of emailOne_ and emailTwo_

Comment: My bad. I didn't know about that

Comment: I suggest that you post a link to godbolt.org with your code and compiler settings.

Comment: You break on "not found" you should instead break on found and store if found in a variable

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have posted a minimal reproducible example

Comment: @Glitchen Great! I've voted to reopen the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues in the code

- `auto found = emailOne_.find(myArray[i]);` will find the `@gmail.com` even if the entered email address is `foo@gmail.com.uk`, which is probably not what you want.
- If the first entry in `myArray` doesn't match, you `break` out and don't test the next.
- If the first entry *is* a match, you *don't* `break` out, so you go on and try the next string in `myArray` which will of course not match - and then you break out.

It's therefore currently impossible to get a valid match. By `break`ing out only when a valid match is found, you should be able to get the correct result.

Example with some suggested simplifications:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    const std::string myArray[] = {"@gmail.com", "@yahoo.com"};

    std::string emailOne_;

    for(;;) {
        std::string emailTwo_;
        std::cout << "Email: ";
        std::cin >> emailOne_;
        std::cout << "Re-enter email: ";
        std::cin >> emailTwo_;

        // simplify comparisons:
        if(emailOne_ != emailTwo_) {
            std::cerr << "\t[*] ERROR: EMAILS DO NOT MATCH\n\n";
            continue; // back to entering email
        }

        bool valid = false;

        // Use range-based for loops to simplify looping over arrays:
        for(const std::string& end : myArray) {

            // check if the end of emailOne_ is equal to `end` by comparing
            // a substring of emailOne_ with the same length as end, with end:

            if(emailOne_.size() > end.size() &&   // must be long enough
               emailOne_.substr(emailOne_.size() - end.size()) == end)
            {
                valid = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // check the valid state after the loop:
        if(!valid) {
            std::cerr << "\t[*] ERROR: EMAILS MUST HAVE @gmail.com or @yahoo.com\n";
        } else {
            break; // a valid email address was found.
        }
    }

    std::cout << emailOne_ << " is a valid address\n";
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help! Base on your edits, I got my code to work

Comment: @Glitchen Glad to hear it! You're welcome!